# TypeError:__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

So, I am a novice in Tensorflow, I have just written a basic code to add two numbers mathematically using a computational graph but it's throwing an error that on running in IPython console :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(4.0)
total = a+b
print(a)
print(b)
print(total)
tf.Tensor("Const:0", dtype='f',shape=[1])
tf.Tensor("Const_1:0", dtype='f',shape =[1])
tf.Tensor("add:0", dtype='f',shape=[1])
```

Error :

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shape'
```

please help & thanks in advance....

Comment: Is there an error line number?

Comment: tf.Tensor("Const:0", dtype='f',shape=[1]) from this line it shows error

Comment: @VivekTalwar  tf.get_variable("v", shape=[1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer) you can set shape like this way

Answer (score 0):

Reading this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor), I understood Tensor has no attribute shape, so you can't give a shape as parameter.

However, what you are looking for is probably [TensorShape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape).

Take also a look to [the Tensor class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py), may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.Tensor("Const:0", dtype='f',shape=[1])
```

in theis line the keword argument "shape=[1]" is the reason for error

when u create an object for

```
tf.Tensor ()
```

it will not have an argument "shape", please remove it and try agin

else if you need to use shape means use it like

```
tf.shape([1])
```